# How to make a custom template to one category in Magento?

Tags: php, xml, magento, templates, themes

I want to make a new theme that will replace only the **list.phtml** file keeping other files like **view.phtml** and call it in one of my categories.
I created the template file on **app/design/frontend/default/newtheme/template/catalog/category/list.phtml** that would replace the current list.phtml file.

Do i have to create a xml file on **app/design/frontend/default/newtheme/layout/**? How it should be?

How do i specify what template file i want use in my category?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you can add your list phtml using below code
:**

```
<reference name="product_list"> 
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>yourfilelocation/yourfile.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
<catalog_category_layered>

<catalog_category_default>
<reference name="product_list"> 
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>yourfilelocation/yourfile.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
<catalog_category_default>
```